# Rotating the values of a row in pyspark

Tags: pyspark

I am currently working on cleaning a dataset and I have been trying to do so using pyspark. The data is read into a dataframe from a csv and the values that I need are in their respective rows, but for some of the rows, the values are mixed up. I need to rotate the values of those rows so that the values are in their correct columns. For example, let's say that I have the following dataset:

```
+-------+-------+-------+
|   A   |   B   |   C   |
+-------+-------+-------+
|   2   |   3   |   1   |
+-------+-------+-------+
```

But the values in the first row should be

```
+-------+-------+-------+
|   A   |   B   |   C   |
+-------+-------+-------+
|   1   |   2   |   3   |
+-------+-------+-------+
```

My current solution is to add a temporary column and to reassign values to each column and rename the temporary column while dropping the old one:

```
// Add temporary column C
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|   A   |   B   |   C   | tmp_C |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|   2   |   3   |   1   |   1   |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
// Shift values
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|   A   |   B   |   C   | tmp_C |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|   2   |   2   |   3   |   1   |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
// Drop old column
+-------+-------+-------+
|   B   |   C   | tmp_C |
+-------+-------+-------+
|   2   |   3   |   1   |
+-------+-------+-------+
// Rename new column
+-------+-------+-------+
|   B   |   C   |   A   |
+-------+-------+-------+
|   2   |   3   |   1   |
+-------+-------+-------+
```

The way I would have this implemented in pyspark is as follows:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.function import when, col

def clean_data(spark_session, file_path):
    df = (
        spark_session
        .read
        .csv(file_path, header='true')
    )

    df = (
        df
        .withColumn(
            "tmp_C",
            when(
                col("C") == 1,
                col("C")
            ).otherwise("A")
        )
        .withColumn(
            "C",
            when(
                col("C") == 1,
                col("B")
            ).otherwise("C")
        )
        .withColumn(
            "B",
            when(
                col("C") == 1,
                col("A")
            ).otherwise("B")
        )
    )

    df = df.drop("A")
    df = df.withColumnRenamed("tmp_C", "A")

    return df
```

To me, this doesn't look too nice and I'm not certain it's the best way to approach this problem. I am quite new to Spark and would like to know the best approach to this situation, although this does work. Also, I would also like to know if this is even a good use case for Spark (note that the dataset that I am using is large and there are many more fields than this. The above example is significantly simplified).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, that could be faster if you map each column by rotation order into it's corresponding column.

```
// generate columns map
maps = dict(zip(['C', 'A', 'B'], ['A', 'B', 'C']))

// regular approach:
// select columns with alias maps
df.select([col(c).alias(maps.get(c, c)) for c in df.columns])

// row scan approach:
// select columns with alias maps that satisfied specific condition
df.select([when(<map-condition>, col(c).alias(maps.get(c, c))).otherwise(col(c)) for c in df.columns])
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Would there be a way to implement this such that the rotation only happens if the row displays is incorrectly formatted (the error is the same on all rows where it exists)? Since some of the rows are correctly formatted, aliasing would result in the data being inversely incorrect. After thinking about the problem a bit more, it sounds like I have no other option except to scan all the rows and perform a rotation with a temporary column. Does this sound right?

Comment: Exactly, this approach could perfect scan for the rows which satisfied map condition associated to incorrect display format. You can check my additional update, and change the <map-condition> to your own custom map condition.

Comment: Awesome, the logic is similar, but this is a much nicer solution. Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome. Keep coding and deploy with confidence!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if the dataset is large you should be using Spark.

You might be better off just re-naming the columns instead of shifting the actual data? Assuming this data issue is systematic like in your example. This is a little convoluted because of issues with re-naming based on column name rather than position, so you will have to change to temp name first.

```
from functools import reduce

old_cols = df.columns
new_cols = old_cols[1:] + [old_cols[0]]
temp_cols = [col + "_" for col in new_cols]
# Rename columns with temporary names
df_temp = reduce(lambda df, idx: df.withColumnRenamed(old_cols[idx], temp_cols[idx]), range(len(old_cols)), df)
# Rename columns to align with correct data
df = reduce(lambda df_temp, idx: df_temp.withColumnRenamed(temp_cols[idx], new_cols[idx]), range(len(temp_cols)), df_temp)
# Then revert back to original column order
df = df.select(old_cols)
```

Comment: One thing I forgot to add in my code is that in each call to `withColumn` I have an argument checking to see if the row has an error (and yes the errors are systematic). So this solution would work if all the rows displayed the same error, but some of the rows are correct. I'll make an edit to reflect that.